# The minimal $f$ such that there is an $n$-vertices $f$-edges graph with every $m$-vertices induced subgraph is connected and has an Eulerian trail

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given positive integers $n$ and $m$ with $n>m$, I want to find the minimal positive integers $f(n,m)$ such that there is a graph with $n$ vertices and $f(n,m)$ edges such that every $m$-vertices induced subgraph is connected and has an Eulerian trail.

It is not difficult to find $f(n,m)$ by exhaustion for fixed small $n$, but I am not sure whether $f(n,m)$ eixsts, and whether there is a closed-form expression for $f(n,m)$ in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $m=2$ or $m$ is odd, we know that $f(n,m)$ exists for every $n$, because $K_n$ satisfies the condition. In particular:

- $f(n,2) = \binom n2$ for all $n$, since a single missing edge gives us an induced $2$-vertex subgraph which is not connected, so $K_n$ is the *only* graph that works.
- $f(n,3) = \binom n2 - \lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$: every induced $3$-vertex subgraph of $G$ has at least two edges if and only if $\overline G$ is a matching with some isolated vertices (and such a $\overline G$ has at most $\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$ edges).

On the other hand, if $m$ is even, then $f(n,m)$ *does not* exist when $n$ is sufficiently large. Take $n$ large enough so that by Ramsey's theorem any $n$-vertex graph $G$ contains either $K_m$ or $\overline{K_m}$ as an induced subgraph; neither of these satisfies the condition we want.